# how to the first and last X axis lables in google line chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, angular-google-chart

I have created a google line chart with the following option, but the first and last X-axis labels are NOT shown, how to fix it?

```
        hAxis: {
          gridlines: {
            count: 9,            
            units: {
              days: {format: ['MMM dd']},
              hours: {format: ['ha']},
            }
          },              
        },
        vAxis: {
          ticks: [0, 54, 70, 180, 250, 350]
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try adding more space for the labels to be displayed,
using the `chartArea`, `left` & `right` options...

```
chartArea: {
  left: 40,   // <-- 40 is arbitrary, increase until they appear
  right: 40
}
```